# How is the crytography system used in Windows XP and does it need to be enabled?

Tags: certificates, windows-xp

The root certificates on my Windows XP machine have expired. As far as I understand it, Windows XP only uses crytography for doing "intranet" data transfers, which in my case is irrelevant because I have no intranet, it is a standalone machine.

Can I just disable the whole crypto API on the machine (which is probably insecure anyway), or does it have a specific necessity to be there?

Comment: You can't disable CryptoAPI on Windows XP (or any other version), because a lot of internal parts of operating systems rely on it. If you don't need it, just don't use.

Comment: Also, you should not rely on XP being secure as it has been EoL/EoS since 2014 and there are VERY few security updates to it at this point (only ones deemed absolutely critical are released for it still).  You should stop using XP as soon as possible and upgrade to a maintained version (or use something else altogether such as macOS or Linux/BSD).

Comment: @Crypt32 Can you be more specific?

Comment: It is enough to mention that LSA (local security authority) actively uses CryptoAPI.